# Find missing sequences by category

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to identify missing records from the example below.

```
Category    BatchNo TransactionNo
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
CAT1           1    1
CAT1           1    2
CAT1           2    3
CAT1           2    4
CAT1           2    5
CAT1           3    6
CAT1           3    7
CAT1           3    8
CAT1           5    12
CAT1           5    13
CAT1           5    14
CAT1           5    15
CAT1           7    18
CAT2           1    1
CAT2           1    2
CAT2           3    6
CAT2           3    7
CAT2           3    8
CAT2           3    9
CAT2           4    10
CAT2           4    11
CAT2           4    12
CAT2           6    14
```

I need a script that will identify missing records as below

```
Category    BatchNo
+++++++++++++++++++
CAT1         4
CAT1         6
CAT2         2
CAT2         5
```

I do not need to know that `CAT1 8` and `CAT2 7` are not there as they potentially have not been inserted yet.

Comment: batch numbers doest go above 6?

Comment: we can see a "7" batch number for CAT1... @NeerajPrasadSharma

Comment: @Neeraj Prasad Sharma no it not......

Comment: so is the max batch num  keep changing?
if cat 2 batch num gone to 8 then cat1 should have gone for batch 8 as well?

Comment: @Neeraj Prasad Sharma no it the only data I have, will not changing

Comment: ok last question in your question cat1 has gone to batch 7 so cat 2 should`t gone to batch 7 ?

Comment: @Neeraj Prasad Sharma ... no no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create temporary result set with all possible batch no up to max batch number for each category than select batch no which are not available.

```
create table TEMP(
        Category varchar(10),
        BatchNo int,
        TransactionNo int
    )
    insert into TEMP values
    ('CAT1', 1, 1),
    ('CAT1', 1, 2),
    ('CAT1', 2, 3),
    ('CAT1', 2, 4),
    ('CAT1', 2, 5),
    ('CAT1', 3, 6),
    ('CAT1', 3, 7),
    ('CAT1', 3, 8),
    ('CAT1', 5, 9),
    ('CAT1', 7, 10),
    ('CAT2', 1, 1),
    ('CAT2', 1, 2),
    ('CAT2', 3, 3),
    ('CAT2', 4, 4),
    ('CAT2', 4, 5),
    ('CAT2', 4, 6),
    ('CAT2', 6, 7);


    WITH BatchNo (BatchID,Category,MaxBatch) AS (
      SELECT 1, Category, MAX(BatchNo) AS MaxBatch  FROM TEMP GROUP BY Category
      UNION ALL
      SELECT BatchID + 1, Category, MaxBatch FROM BatchNo
      WHERE BatchID < MaxBatch
    )

    SELECT 
        BatchNo.Category,
        BatchNo.BatchID
    FROM 
        BatchNo
    WHERE 
        BatchID NOT IN (SELECT BatchNo FROM TEMP WHERE Category = BatchNo.Category)
    ORDER BY
        BatchNo.Category,
        BatchNo.BatchID


    DROP TABLE TEMP
```

Answer (score 0):

This one uses a `Tally Table`. For reference: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
create table MyTable(
    Category varchar(10),
    BatchNo int,
    TransactionNo int
)
insert into MyTable values
('CAT1', 1, 1),
('CAT1', 1, 2),
('CAT1', 2, 3),
('CAT1', 2, 4),
('CAT1', 2, 5),
('CAT1', 3, 6),
('CAT1', 3, 7),
('CAT1', 3, 8),
('CAT1', 5, 12),
('CAT1', 5, 13),
('CAT1', 5, 14),
('CAT1', 5, 15),
('CAT1', 7, 18),
('CAT2', 1, 1),
('CAT2', 1, 2),
('CAT2', 3, 6),
('CAT2', 3, 7),
('CAT2', 3, 8),
('CAT2', 3, 9),
('CAT2', 4, 10),
('CAT2', 4, 11),
('CAT2', 4, 12),
('CAT2', 6, 14);
```

## SOLUTION

```
with e1(n) as (
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1
),  --10e+1 or 10 rows
e2(n) as (select 1 from e1 a, e1 b), --10e+2 or 100 rows
e4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows
tally(n) as(
    select 
        top (select top 1 BatchNo from MyTable order by BatchNo desc)
        row_number() over(order by (select null))
    from e4
)
select  
    c.Category,
    t.n
from tally t
cross join(
    select 
        Category, 
        max(BatchNo) as MaxBatchNo 
    from MyTable 
    group by Category
)c
left join MyTable m
    on m.BatchNo = t.n
    and m.Category = c.Category
where
    m.Category is null 
    and t.n < c.MaxBatchNo
order by
    c.Category,
    t.n
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create a projection table and use standard `left join` to find gaps:

```
declare @Sequencer table (
    Id int primary key
);

insert into @Sequencer (Id)
select top (1000) row_number() over(order by (select null)) from master.dbo.spt_values;

select *
from @Sequencer s
    inner join (
        select Category, max(BatchNo) as [Size] from dbo.Table group by Category
    ) cat on cat.Size > s.Id
    left join (
        select distinct Category, BatchNo from dbo.Table
    ) t on t.Category = cat.Category and t.BatchNo = s.Id
where t.BatchNo is null;
```

Of course, in real life you might need more than 1000 rows, so adjust it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Numbers AS (
    SELECT MAX(BatchNo) AS Number
    FROM #MyTable
  UNION ALL
    SELECT Number - 1
    FROM Numbers
    WHERE Number > 1
)
,CategorySizes AS (
    SELECT Category
          ,MIN(BatchNo) AS StartBatch
          ,MAX(BatchNo) AS EndBatch
    FROM #MyTable
    GROUP BY Category
)
,PossibleBatches AS (
    SELECT Category
          ,Numbers.Number AS BatchNo
    FROM CategorySizes
         CROSS JOIN Numbers
    WHERE Numbers.Number BETWEEN CategorySizes.StartBatch AND CategorySizes.EndBatch                
)
,MissingBatches AS (
    SELECT PossibleBatches.Category
          ,PossibleBatches.BatchNo
    FROM PossibleBatches
         LEFT JOIN #MyTable
            ON #MyTable.Category = PossibleBatches.Category
               AND #MyTable.BatchNo = PossibleBatches.BatchNo
    WHERE #MyTable.BatchNo IS NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM MissingBatches
```

Answer (score 0):

without use cycle or fetch you can use this one: (#Category is my eqvivalent of your table name). (Performance is perfect)

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (RN INT IDENTITY,Category VARCHAR(255), BatchNo INT)

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT DISTINCT Category, BatchNo
FROM #Category

SELECT a.Category,a.BatchNo+1 AS BatchNo 
FROM @t a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM @t b 
                      WHERE a.RN+1 = b.RN AND 
                            a.Category = b.Category AND 
                            a.BatchNo+1 != b.BatchNo) x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #cat(
        Category varchar(10),
        BatchNo int,
        TransactionNo int
    )
insert into #cat values
    ('CAT1', 1, 1),
    ('CAT1', 1, 2),
    ('CAT1', 2, 3),
    ('CAT1', 2, 4),
    ('CAT1', 2, 5),
    ('CAT1', 3, 6),
    ('CAT1', 3, 7),
    ('CAT1', 3, 8),
    ('CAT1', 5, 9),
    ('CAT1', 7, 10),
    ('CAT2', 1, 1),
    ('CAT2', 1, 2),
    ('CAT2', 3, 3),
    ('CAT2', 4, 4),
    ('CAT2', 4, 5),
    ('CAT2', 4, 6),
    ('CAT2', 6, 7);


SELECT DISTINCT C.Category, C.BatchNo + 1
FROM #cat c
OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM #cat c1
        WHERE C1.BatchNo = C.BatchNo + 1 AND C1.Category = C.Category
) C2
WHERE C2.BatchNo IS NULL 
      AND 
      C.BatchNo <> (SELECT MAX(BatchNo) FROM #cat C3 WHERE c3.Category = c.Category)
```